# Installed fonts not detected on firefox 99 snap on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: firefox, fonts, snap

I am trying to use my installed fonts on the Firefox snap but I can't get it working. I'm trying to force a custom font on all pages using the [`Stylish`](https://userstyles.org/).

Here's my script:

```css
html > body  {font-family: "SF Compact Display"}
html > body > code {font-family: "SF Mono"}
```

I have installed both the fonts above and this code is working on the all other browsers I have (including the deb version of firefox) but not on the Snap version of firefox. None of my system fonts can be used in web pages. I can't use the Firefox deb version because of Widevine crashes and other minor issues.

How do I get Firefox to detect the installed fonts?

Comment: Related issues in issue trackers: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1760996 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1916867

Comment: Keep in mind, that snaps are by default isolated from the system.

If you want to add fonts to it, copy font files to the folder `/snap/firefox/current/usr/lib/firefox/fonts`

Answer (score 3):

As [@DamianYerrick](https://askubuntu.com/users/232993/damian-yerrick) in his comment, this is a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1760996) in the snap version of Firefox (or more correctly, an upstream [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1916867) in `snapd`).

As a workaround, there's a interim solution recommended in [comment #11](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1760996#c11) of the Firefox bug — creating a symlink from within the Firefox snap directory pointing to the local font directory:

```
ln -s ~/.local/share/fonts ~/snap/firefox/current/.local/share/fonts
```

I've tested this, and it works for me. <s>Not sure if I'll have to repeat the command once the snap updates to a new version, though, considering that `~/snap/firefox/current` is a symlink to (at the time of writing) `~/snap/firefox/2710`.</s>

Update: I had to repeat this command after Firefox got updated, and restart Firefox for the change to take effect. I tried adding the symlink to `~/snap/firefox/common` but that didn't seem to be picked up by the browser.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!